WP_Query with multiple categories unexpected behavior
I'm working on a custom filter that uses checkboxes to choose which categories to show. I'm trying to get it show posts based on selecting more than one category. When I test with hard coded ID's it works as planned, but when I use $_POST[] to get categories dynamically I always get the same posts.
    $cats = $_POST['cats'];
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => $_POST['page'],
        'category__in' => $cats, // doesn't work and console on the returned data shows ['6', '2']
        // 'category__in' => ['6', '2'] // works
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        $results[] = array(
            'post' => $post,
            'img_url' => wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full'),
            'title' => $post->post_title,
            'link' => get_permalink($post->ID),
            'max_page' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'test' => $cats
        );
    }
    
    wp_send_json_success($results);

The 'category__in' => ['6', '2'] works and I get the 5 expected posts but $cats only gives me posts with the ID of 6. I'm not sure where I'm messing up. Any help would be great.

Try doing a compare of $cats with [ '6', '2' ] (ex: var_dump( $cats === [ '6', '2' ] );) and see if PHP reports that the two variables are equal. If they're not, then there's something askew with the $_POST data.

To get an array from a form POST into PHP, you have to name the form variable with square brackets:
<html>
<body>
<pre>
<?php var_export( $_POST ); ?>
</pre>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label> 4<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="4"></label>
    <label> 5<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="5"></label>
    <label> 6<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" value="6"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>

